# how to comeout from BeanShell Sampler after running the script

Tags: jmeter

I have wrote a script in BeanShell Sampler, which call for a java thread through script, while start the script in jmeter consol its keep on running, so I am not comeout from BeanShell Sampler and unable to proceed to next step in jmeter

Someone please help me, how to comeout from BeanShell Sampler after running the script

Regards
Ranjan

Answer (score 0):

In Beanshell Sampler you have a [number of pre-defined variables](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell), like:

- vars
- props
- ctx
- log

The one you need is SampleResult which is an instance of [org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)

The methods you may find useful are:

1. [setStopThread](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setStopThread%28boolean%29) - the most lenient one, probably the one you're looking for
2. [setStopTest](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setStopTest%28boolean%29) - will stop entire test (will tell all samples to stop)
3. [setStopTestNow](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setStopTestNow%28boolean%29) - force stop entire test, doesn't wait for samples to gracefully shutdown, you may receive unexpected errors if decide to use this option so be careful

So I guess that you need to place next code line at the bottom of your Beanshell Sampler:

```
SampleResult.setStopThread(true);
```